# How to see boost::multi_index hashed index's data using gdb

Tags: c++, boost, gdb, multi-index

I'd like to see the data contained by boost::multi_index(version 1.67.0) using gdb.
First I tried https://github.com/ruediger/Boost-Pretty-Printer.
It seems that hashed indexes such as `hashed_unique` are not supported.

I noticed that if the first index is a supported type such as `sequenced`, Boost-Pretty-Printer works fine.
However, I cannot edit the code now. I need to debug a core file and a binary executable.

I tried to understand the internal structure of multi_index with hashed index.

I worte the following test code:

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>

namespace mi = boost::multi_index;

struct t_hash{};

using elems = mi::multi_index_container<
    int,
    mi::indexed_by<
        mi::hashed_unique<
            mi::tag<t_hash>,
            mi::identity<int>
        >
    >
>;

int main() {
    elems es { 0x12, 0x34 };
    return 0; // set break point here and (gdb) p es
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/UtMfVRI4rT5AXUOZ

When I print es, `(gdb) p es` I got the following output:

```
$1 = {
  <boost::base_from_member<std::allocator<boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<int, std::allocator<int> >, boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_unique_tag> >, 0>> = {
    member = {
      <__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<int, std::allocator<int> >, boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_unique_tag> >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}
  },
  <boost::multi_index::detail::header_holder<boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<int, std::allocator<int> >, boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_unique_tag>*, boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<int, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<t_hash, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::identity<int>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::allocator<int> > >> = {
    <boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable> = {<No data fields>},
    members of boost::multi_index::detail::header_holder<boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<int, std::allocator<int> >, boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_unique_tag>*, boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<int, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<t_hash, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::identity<int>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::allocator<int> > >:
    member = 0x55555576ee70
  },
  <boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index<boost::multi_index::identity<int>, boost::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<1, int, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<t_hash, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::identity<int>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::allocator<int> >, boost::mpl::v_item<t_hash, boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>, 0>, boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_unique_tag>> = {
    <boost::multi_index::detail::index_base<int, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<t_hash, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::identity<int>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::allocator<int> >> = {<No data fields>},
    members of boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index<boost::multi_index::identity<int>, boost::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<1, int, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<t_hash, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::identity<int>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::allocator<int> >, boost::mpl::v_item<t_hash, boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>, 0>, boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_unique_tag>:
    key = {
      <boost::multi_index::detail::non_const_identity_base<int>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>},
    hash_ = {
      <boost::hash_detail::hash_base<int>> = {
        <std::unary_function<int, unsigned long>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>},
    eq_ = {
      <std::binary_function<int, int, bool>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>},
    buckets = {
      <boost::multi_index::detail::bucket_array_base<true>> = {
        <boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable> = {<No data fields>},
      },
      members of boost::multi_index::detail::bucket_array<std::allocator<int> >:
      size_index_ = 0,
      spc = {
        <boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable> = {<No data fields>},
        members of boost::multi_index::detail::auto_space<boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_base_node_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<int> >:
        al_ = {
          <__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_base_node_impl<std::allocator<char> > >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>},
        n_ = 54,
        data_ = 0x55555576ee90
      }
    },
    mlf = 1,
    max_load = 53
  },
  members of boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<int, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<t_hash, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::identity<int>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::allocator<int> >:
  node_count = 2
}
```

I found `node_count = 2`. It seems that the number of elements. I tried digging the member variables. e.g.) `member`, `buckets`, and so on. But I cannot found the data `0x12` and `0x34`, so far.

How do I get them?

---

## Edit: 2018/07/28 11:51 JST

Thanks for the comments, I found the solution. I summarize two approaches based on the comments.

### Runtime shared library loading based on @sehe 's approach,

1. Write a debug print function (`debug_print()`) as a shared library (`dp.so`).
2. run gdb. `gdb target_executable_file`
3. Do `set environment LD_PRELOAD ./dp.so`.
4. Set breakpoints.
5. Do `r`
6. When the breakpoint hits, do `call debug_print(data)`. `data` is the target you want to see.

This approach does't need to re-compile the target. However, when I load core file, `debug_print()` is no longer on memory. So this approach doesn't work with core file.
I'm looking for forcibly load `dp.so` after core-file loaded, but I couldn't find the way, so far.

### Trace multi_index's internal structure using gdb

This approach is work with core-file.
This approach is based on @Joaquín M López Muñoz 's comment.

1. Run gdb with core file. `gdb target_executable_file core_file`.
2. Do the following command to access the data. `T` is multi_index's element type. `data` is multi_index container variable. `N` is number of indexes.

1st data

`p *(T*)((char*)(*data.member).prior_ - sizeof(T) - 0x10 * (N - 1))`

2nd data

`p *(T*)((char*)(*(*data.member).prior_).prior_ - sizeof(T) - 0x10 * (N - 1))`

...follow the same pattern.

Thank you very much @sele and @Joaquín M López Muñoz !!

---

## Edit: 2018/07/28 15:22 JST

I implemented hashed indexes support for Boost-Pretty-Printer. It is based on the above approach.

I sent the pull request for that:

https://github.com/ruediger/Boost-Pretty-Printer/pull/36

---

## Edit: 2018/07/28 15:42 JST

I figured out what 0x10 mean. It is pointer size multiplies 2. So in 64bit environment, 64bit = 8byte, 8 * 2 = 16 = 0x10.
In 32bit environment 32bit = 4byte, 4 * 2 = 8 = 0x08.

I also updated the pull request.

---

## Edit: 2018/08/02 09:30 JST

Finally, I sent two pull requests and both are merged. Now, we can simple use Boost-Pretty-Printer and print the multi_index container that has hashed_index as the first index.

https://github.com/ruediger/Boost-Pretty-Printer/pull/36

https://github.com/ruediger/Boost-Pretty-Printer/pull/37

Here is internal structure and iterating algorithm:

https://speakerdeck.com/redboltz/boost-multi-index-version-equals-1-dot-56-dot-0-internal-structure-and-iteration-algorithm-for-gdb-boost-prerry-printer

Comment: Maybe you can promote your updates to an answer. I'd life to award my bounty to your effort to get those pull requests in. Of course you can keep the accepted answer no problem and hopefully the extra attention will benefit it too.

Comment: @sehe, thank you for the comment. I can see the message `This question has an open bounty worth +250 reputation from sehe ending in 4 days.` above. I've read the help page for bounty. But I don't understand what I can do. How can I promote my updates to answer? Do I need to post an new answer by myself? Or is there any way to set my edit to answer?

Comment: Indeed I meant you can to manually create an answer from the information that you have edited into the question,  sorry for my confusing wording.

Comment: OK, I will post my answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution for new Boost version

If you are using Boost 1.56.0 or later, you can print the container using Boost-Pretty-Printer.

### Install Boost-Pretty-Printer

The github site is https://github.com/ruediger/Boost-Pretty-Printer

Installation manual is https://github.com/ruediger/Boost-Pretty-Printer#installation

### Do print command on gdb.

Then, you can get the result.

If you have already installed Boost-Pretty-Printer and couldn't getpretty print result, you need to update it.

hashed_index support is introduced since
https://github.com/ruediger/Boost-Pretty-Printer/commit/d8557f664e0dd3d11bb0464d8f670e99946e88b9

## Solution for old Boost version

If you are using Boost version less than 1.56.0, you have some choices.

### 1. Updating boost.

Just update your boost library and re-compile your program.

#### Pros

- If you can do, it's the easiest way.

#### Cons

- It requires re-compile the target.
- It might introduce comatibility problem to your application.
- It doesn't work with existing binary executable and core file.

### 2. Dynamic loading shared library

Writing debug print function. Here is the code example:

dp.cpp

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>

namespace mi = boost::multi_index;

struct t_hash{};

// define the same structure of the debug target
using elems = mi::multi_index_container<
    int,
    mi::indexed_by<
        mi::hashed_unique<
            mi::tag<t_hash>,
            mi::identity<int>
        >
    >
>;

#include <iostream>

// debug print function
void dp(elems const& es) {
    for (auto const& e : es) {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Compile it using the same compiler option as the target. And add `-fPIC` for shared library.

`clang++ -g -c dp.cpp -fPIC`

Then you get `dp.o`

Link it as a shared library

`clang++ -shared -o dp.so dp.o`

Then you get `dp.so`

Run gdb. `gdb target_executable_file`

Do `set environment LD_PRELOAD ./dp.so`.

Set breakpoints.

Do `r`

When the breakpoint hits, do `call dp(data)`. data is the target you want to see

#### Pros

- Re-compile the target is not required.

#### Cons

- Doesn't work with core file.

### 3. Develop Boost-Pretty-Print support for older version

Unfortunately, current Boost-Pretty-Print hashed_indexes supports only Boost 1.56.0 or later. But you can implement older support by yourself.

Here is the data structure description that is focused on iteration and iteration algorithm for >= 1.56 version. I think that it is a good hint to implement older version iteration algorithm.

https://speakerdeck.com/redboltz/boost-multi-index-version-equals-1-dot-56-dot-0-internal-structure-and-iteration-algorithm-for-gdb-boost-prerry-printer

And my pull requests (merged).
https://github.com/ruediger/Boost-Pretty-Printer/pull/36

https://github.com/ruediger/Boost-Pretty-Printer/pull/37

For < 1.56 version, I wrote the program to check the internal structure.

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace mi = boost::multi_index;

struct t_hash{};

using elems = mi::multi_index_container<
    int,
    mi::indexed_by<
        mi::hashed_non_unique<
            mi::tag<t_hash>,
            mi::identity<int>
        >
    >
>;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto size = boost::lexical_cast<int>(argv[1]);
    elems es;
    for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        es.insert(i);
    }
    return 0; // break here
}
```

And I got the following gdb output:

```
b 30
r 5

p es.member
0x555555770e70

p (*es.member).next_
0x555555771038

p (*(*es.member).next_).next_
0x555555770e78

p (*(*(*es.member).next_).next_).next_
0x555555771038

...


x /200xb 0x555555771030

0x555555771030: 0x30    0x10    0x77    0x55    0x55    0x55    0x00    0x00
0x555555771038: 0x78    0x0e    0x77    0x55    0x55    0x55    0x00    0x00
0x555555771040: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x555555771048: 0x21    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00


0x555555771050: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
0x555555771058: 0x90    0x0e    0x77    0x55    0x55    0x55    0x00    0x00
0x555555771060: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x555555771068: 0x21    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00


0x555555771070: 0x01    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
0x555555771078: 0x98    0x0e    0x77    0x55    0x55    0x55    0x00    0x00
0x555555771080: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x555555771088: 0x21    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00


0x555555771090: 0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
0x555555771098: 0xa0    0x0e    0x77    0x55    0x55    0x55    0x00    0x00
0x5555557710a0: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x5555557710a8: 0x21    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00


0x5555557710b0: 0x03    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
0x5555557710b8: 0xa8    0x0e    0x77    0x55    0x55    0x55    0x00    0x00
0x5555557710c0: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x5555557710c8: 0x21    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00


0x5555557710d0: 0x04    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
0x5555557710d8: 0xb0    0x0e    0x77    0x55    0x55    0x55    0x00    0x00
0x5555557710e0: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x5555557710e8: 0x21    0xef    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00

0x5555557710f0: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
...
```

This information and @Joaquín M López Muñoz's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549875/how-to-see-boostmulti-index-hashed-indexs-data-using-gdb/51664660?noredirect=1#comment90348664_51664660) also could be a good hint to implement the < 1.56 Boost-Pretty-Printer.

#### Pros

- Re-compile the target is not required.
- Work well with core file.

#### Cons

- You need to implement Boost-Pretty-Printer support.

Comment: There's an error in this summary concerning pre-1.56 implementation of hashed indices. As it happens, pictures 1 and 3 on the article you link refer to a design that never made it into an official release. Prior to Boost 1.56, hashed indices were implemented as a singly linked list with bucket array entries linked in between elements --one can tell whether a particular node is an actual node or a bucket array entry by comparing with the range of addresses of the bucket array.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error. I will update my answer later.

Answer (score 3):

I've looked at the implementation of those Python pretty printers and I agree that it's not going to be easy.

Maybe you can define some debug-printing functions in another place, like another translation unit that you *can* modify, or even in another library that you then PRELOAD. If you do the latter, make absolutely sure you are using the same library/compiler versions and flags or you'll simply get undefined results. In both scenarios, ensure that the function isn't optimized out at link time.

You could then use the `gdb` `call` command to evaluate that function, like so:

[image]

Comment: @HenriMenke I'm using i3wm (which is a tiling wm). The editor is vim and the debugger integration is Pyclewn

Comment: @sehe, thank you for the comment. I cannot edit any part of the executable file. So I think that make shared library that contains the debug print function and PRELOAD it, as you mentioned. I will try this approach.

Comment: I made the shared object that contains debug print function. Then do `set environment LD_PRELOAD ./debug_print.so` on gdb. Then set the break point and run the target. Finally, `call debug_print(es)` on gdb, and got value. Thank you very much!

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo that's actually cool that you got it to work. Well done and thanks for letting me know

Comment: shared library approach works fine when I PRELOAD so file and then run the target executable. However, when I load core file, it doesn't seems to work. I saved core file. Then run `gdb execfile`. Then `set environment LD_PRELOAD ./debug_print.so`. Then `core-file core.1`. Then `call debug_print(es)`, but I got the message `No symbol "debug_print" in current context`. Maybe `so` file is not loaded or overwritten...

Comment: Loading a core file doesn't create a process.  Hence no runtime linker is involved and preloading doesn't apply

Comment: Yes. And I couldn't find the way working core-file and shared-library together, so far. By the way, https://github.com/ruediger/Boost-Pretty-Printer/pull/36 is merged just now.

Comment: That is great reward. Thanks for the question here, and improving life for others

Answer (score 2):

The hash table structure of Boost.MultiIndex is depicted on the second figure of [this article](http://bannalia.blogspot.com/2014/01/a-better-hash-table.html). Complex as it looks, turns out you can traverse all the nodes in reverse order starting from the dummy header node (used to signal the container's end) and following the `prior_` pointers. This header node is pointed to by `member` in `boost::multi_index::detail::header_holder<...>`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I can get 0x12 and 0x34 on my example. I use the following command. `p/x *(int*)((char*)(*es.member).prior_ - 0x08)` then I got
`$28 = 0x34`. And `p/x *(int*)((char*)(*(*es.member).prior_).prior_ - 0x08)` then I got `$29 = 0x12`. I'm just trying to get the value, I'm not sure -8 bytes is correct, but I will apply the same way to my target executable and core file. Thanks.

Comment: When I change the data type from int to other type such as a `std::string`, this approach doesn't work. Maybe I need to adjust the pointer position some how.

Comment: You have to subtract `sizeof(value_type)` plus padding.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I worte https://wandbox.org/permlink/PuPiQDppwhPO3NvJ and printed expected result. See the end of comment. It works if the index is one. However, if I add one more index, the result has been changed. https://wandbox.org/permlink/FYld0vpaT1SGMaqQ is it. I guess that I need more pointer adjustment.

Comment: `p/x *(elem*)((char*)(*es.member).prior_ - sizeof(elem) - 0x10)` returns `$4 = { x = 0x56, y = "DEF", z = 0x78` , and `p/x *(elem*)((char*)(*(*es.member).prior_).prior_ - sizeof(elem) - 0x10)` returns `$4 = { x = 0x12, y = "ABC", z = 0x34` .  I'm still analyzing.

Comment: After some try and error, I got the pattern. `prior_ - sizeof(element_type) - 0x10 * (number_of_indexes - 1)` is the data address.